# MVC Customizing display template: Model.Value vs @ViewData.Model

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I've seen two "Display templates customezing" examples.

In the 1. example programmer use Model.Value and in the 2. example he use @ViewData.Model.- See below

Exampel 1 (DateTime view:)

```
@model DateTime?
@Html.TextBox("", Model.HasValue ? Model.Value.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy") : "", new { @class = "ka_" })
```

Example 2:

```
<a href="@ViewData.Model" target="_blank">@ViewData.Model<a/>
```

What is the difference between them ?

What to select ?

Comment: Short answer - Nothing (the `ViewDataDictionary` passed to the view by your controller contains a property `Model` which is the model you passed to the view)

Comment: Programmer sends "ViewModel" from Controller to View in both examples.

He does not send ViewData object from the controller to the view

Comment: The **controller method** initializes a `ViewDataDictionary` (`ViewData`) and passes it to the view (and populates its `Model` property)

Comment: Maybe I do not understand what you mean.

But he forward this model from controlle action method to view

public class house
{
  public DateTime? Hire{get; set;}

  [DataType(DataType.Url)]
  public String Website{get; set;}
}

Comment: Yes, and when you use `return View(...)` the controller creates a `ViewDataDictionary` (a property of the controller named `ViewData`) and adds that model to it `Model` property and passes it to the view.

Comment: Very interesting.

This means that when we send an object or a list of objects to view. Then return View (), stores it in ViewData.Model

And from View can we call ViewData.Model

Comment: Yes if you want to, but why - far easier to use `@Model`

Comment: I expect when we use @MODEL so it also read data from ViewData.MODEL ??

(Iam learning mvc,,...and I always use @Model)

Comment: I dont know how to accept your answer.

Comment: I have not added an answer :) - but feel free to add you own and accept it to close this out

Answer (score 0):

In most cases you use both in your views. The model specifies the data for you're main view. It's the data that is created by the controller action. The ViewData dictionary is normally populated by other components.

Let's take for example an Product (view)model. A product would have a price, a description, a sku and in most cases a stock indication.

You're Product (view)model does not contain data any user information, website navigational data. That data is placed in the ViewData dictionary by other components and can be used by (parent) views to render the full page.

A bit offtopic, but at our company we have a very strict rules about what a view is allowed to do. In short is it not allowed to change/modify any data (not even the page title!) or to retrieve any data. The only code allowed in our views are conditional constructs and calls to helper methods. It helps if new developers on the team start with view engines that have no an 'eval' constructs like SuperSimpleViewEngine (from NancyFx) or XsltViewEngine. Razor and WebForms make it to easy to 'cheat'..

Comment: This has nothing to do with what OP is asking!